# Invoke ContainerStoppingErrorHandler based on exception type

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka version 2.2.4 Release and Kafka version 2.11. I am using **ContainerStoppingErrorHandler** as my error handler. Whenever there is an exception this method is called and stops the container. Now I need to stop the container based on the exception type if some DB exception occurs it should stop the container for other exception types it should send email to the group.  Below is my error handler code

```
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<byte[], byte[]> messageKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
//consumer configs...
factory.setErrorHandler(new ContainerStoppingErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                MessageListenerContainer container) {


            if (thrownException instanceof ConnectionException) {

                LOGGER.error("Database exception occured stopping the container");
                super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);

            } else {
                //send email about error without discarding the records
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am able to stop the container based on the DB exception but for other exceptions the records in the poll including the error record is getting discarded so I am losing the data. ***Is there any way to handle the exceptions based on the type and invoke error handler if DB exception stop else continue without discarding the remaining records like that.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For other exceptions, delegate to a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` which will cause seeks for the topics for all the unprocessed records (including the failed record) so they will be redelivered on the next poll().

The STCEH gives up on the failed record after 10 attempts by default, but you can change that by setting the `maxAttempts` constructor argument.

**EDIT**

```java
factory.setErrorHandler(new ContainerStoppingErrorHandler() {

        private final SeekToCurrentErrorHandler stceh = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(...);

        @Override
        public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                MessageListenerContainer container) {


            if (thrownException.getCause() instanceof ConnectionException) {

                LOGGER.error("Database exception occured stopping the container");
                super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);

            } else {
                //send email about error without discarding the records
                this.stceh.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler I want to know how I can invoke that based on my exception type. In my code I have configured only the ContainerStoppingErrorHandler . How can I configure SeekToCurrentErrorHandler to my error handler based on the type? Any sample code would be helpful for me

Comment: Just delegate to it from the else block - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: If i configure a spring boot actuator health check combined with ContainerStoppingErrorHandler, would my health check report DOWN.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers; it doesn't help others looking for help; current versions will report DOWN; earlier versions did not look at container state.